# React Material ui input field to custom

Tags: reactjs, input, field

Hi does anyone have any idea to make the input field behave like this example?

https://www.westpac.com.au/personal-banking/home-loans/calculator/mortgage-calculator/

we should not allow user to delete 0 and when user type should replace 0 with the value, and when we delete all the value, the cursor will always stays at the end of the first digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code should work the way you want it.

```js
function theFunction(e) {
  if (e.value <= 0) return e.value = 0
  if (e.value[0] == 0) return e.value = e.value.substring(1)
}
```

```css
body{
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
}

.custom-input {
      border-top-right-radius: 4px;
      border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
      background-color: rgb(42, 46, 66);
      color: rgb(249, 249, 251);
      padding: 18px;
      font-size: 48px;
      height: 84px;
      margin-bottom: 18px;
      border-color: rgb(171, 175, 177);
}
```

```html
<body>
      <input type="number" class="custom-input" id="custom-input" oninput="theFunction(this)" value="800">
</body>
```

Comment: This is exactly the behavior that i wanted. however I need it in my react component which is using textfield and react number format

Comment: you can simply wrap it inside a function, then call it within the element with the onChange attr. e.g <TextField
  onChange={theFunction}
/> I will edit the above code to work as a function or middleware

Comment: TextField: <TextField onInput={theFunction(this)} />....   react-number-format: <NumberFormat 
  onValueChange={theFunction(this)}
/>

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use the if condition in your handleChange function, for example :

```
...
var result = 0;
if(input <= 0 || input == ''){
   result = 0;
} else {
   result = event.target.value;
}

this.setState({
    inputValue: result
})
...
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thanks for this.. my implementation is with react hook form and mui textfield with react-number-format. tried it and didn't work as expected.